# "Could not resolve hostname" Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

I have created my first ansible playbook according to [this tutorial](http://abregman.com/2015/12/25/ansible-write-and-run-your-first-playbook/), so it looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: hostb
  tasks:
      - name: Create file
        file:
            path: /tmp/yallo
            state: touch

- hosts: my_hosts
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
      - name: Create user
        user:
            name: mario
            shell: /bin/zsh

      - name: Install zlib
        yum:
            name: zlib
            state: latest
```

However, I can not figure out which hosts I should put into my hosts file. I have something like this for now:

```
[my_hosts]
hostA
hostB
```

Obviously, it is not working and I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostb: Name or service not known
```

So how should I change my hosts file? I am new to ansible so I would be very grateful for some help!

Comment: I know that, but in this tutorial, there is only a name and I have no idea which IP addresses should be there.

Comment: Please contact the blog author, if you feel it’s unclear. There is a comment form at the bottom of the page. StackOverflow is not a tutoring site; this has nothing to do with programming, and as I already mentioned, nobody but you knows how to access your machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so the Ansible inventory can be based on following format:

- HostName => `IP Address`
- HostName => `DHCP or Hosts file hostname reference localhost/cassie.local`
- Create your own alias => `hostname ansible_host=IP Address`
- Group of hosts => `[group_name]`

That is the most basic structure you can use.

> Example

```
# Grouping
[test-group]

# IP reference
192.168.1.3

# Local hosts file reference
localhost

# Create your own alias
test ansible_host=192.168.1.4

# Create your alias with port and user to login as
test-2 ansible_host=192.168.1.5 ansible_port=1234 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

---

> #### Grouping of hosts will only end when the end of file or another group detected. So if you wish to have hosts that don't belong to a group, make sure they're defined above the group definition.

I.E. everything in the above example is belong to `test-group`, and if you do following; it will execute on all of the hosts:

`ansible test-group -u ubuntu -m ping`

---

Answer (score 0):

ansible is case sensitive host name in your inventory file is hostB and in your playbook is hostb i think way its showing " Name or service not known" error

change your host name in the playbook to hostB